# Optimization sql query. How can i reach that?

Tags: sql, optimization

```
select * from
(select t.id,
        t.num,
        t.declaration_Date,
        ct.type,
        g.name,
        g.tnved_code,
        g.g31_amount,
        g.brutto,
        g.netto,
        case
            when t.state = 1 then
                1
            else
                0
            end
                                                         env,
        CASE
            WHEN ct.type = 1 THEN
                t.g2_code2
            ELSE
                '200794867'
            END                                       as seller_tin,
        CASE
            WHEN ct.type = 1 THEN
                '200794867'
            ELSE
                t.g8_code2
            END                                       as buyer_tin,
        CASE
            WHEN ct.type = 1 THEN
                t.g2_name
            ELSE
                t.g8_name
            END                                       as seller_name,
        CASE
            WHEN ct.type = 2 THEN
                t.g8_name
            ELSE
                t.g2_name
            END                                       as buyer_name,
        sum(g.cost_facture * t.curr_Course)           as cost_Facture,
        SUM(g1.good_payment_27 + g2.good_pay_late_27) as good_payment_27,
        SUM(g1.good_payment_29 + g2.good_pay_late_29) as good_payment_29
 from valyuta_declarations t,
      valyuta_CONTRACT_SUB_TYPES ct,
      valyuta_GOODS g,
      (select g.id,
              g.declaration_id,
              g.cost_facture,
              SUM(CASE
                      WHEN gp.payment_code = 27 THEN
                          gp.payment_amount
                      ELSE
                          0
                  END) as good_payment_27,
              SUM(CASE
                      WHEN gp.payment_code = 29 THEN
                          gp.payment_amount
                      ELSE
                          0
                  END) as good_payment_29
       from valyuta_goods g,
            valyuta_good_payments gp
       where g.id = gp.good_id(+)
       group by g.id, g.declaration_id, g.cost_facture) g1,
      (select g.id,
              g.declaration_id,
              g.cost_facture,
              SUM(CASE
                      WHEN gpl.L_G47_TYPE = 27 THEN
                          gpl.L_G47_SUM
                      ELSE
                          0
                  END) as good_pay_late_27,
              SUM(CASE
                      WHEN gpl.L_G47_TYPE = 29 THEN
                          gpl.L_G47_SUM
                      ELSE
                          0
                  END) as good_pay_late_29
       from valyuta_goods g,
            valyuta_GOOD_PAY_LATE gpl
       where g.id = gpl.good_id(+)
       group by g.id, g.declaration_id, g.cost_facture) g2

 where t.type = ct.short_name
   and t.id = g.DECLARATION_ID
   and g.id = g1.id
   and g.id = g2.id
   and ((ct.type = 1 and t.g1_b in (10, 11)) or (ct.type = 2 and t.g1_b = 40))
 GROUP BY t.id,
          t.num,
          t.declaration_Date,
          t.state,
          ct.type,
          g.name,
          g.tnved_code,
          g.g31_amount,
          g.brutto,
          g.netto,
          t.G2_CODE2,
          t.G2_NAME,
          t.g8_code2,
          t.g8_name) a
where a.type = 1 and a.env = 1 and a.declaration_date between to_date('01-01-2022','dd-mm-yyyy') and to_date('31-03-2022','dd-mm-yyyy')
and seller_tin in ('302857893')
```

There is my code. It takes 30 minutes to see result. How can i optimize that?
I have no idea how to optimize that.

Comment: Please EDIT your post.  Please supply some sample data.  Your query group has a case/when construct to get buyer / seller, but group is by type = 1, so you would never have 1 record that showed both buyer and seller.  What is the true unique ID.  If the ID is for a transaction and can be one:more buyer and seller, what then?  Your group by has no consideration of MIN/MAX in such considerations.  Again, please EDIT your post and show samples of data of both "TYPE" values and expected output.  Obviously fake data such as name information, but provide actual context.

Answer (score 0):

To improve on the performance of that query, you'll want to have a look at the execution plan first. Most SQL server editions offer hints to create indexes. Creating those will already result in a considerable speed-up, in particular in the subqueries. The numbers on the execution plan items will tell you where the critical path is: rearranging parts of the query, or changing the location where expensive joins and comparisons are made, will speed things up.

The `valuyuta...` group of tables needs to use the proper join syntax (`INNER JOIN`). The fragments `and g.id = g1.id` and `and g.id = g2.id` can then be removed from the `WHERE` clause and go to the join criteria of their respective table.

Furthermore, techniques exist to get rid of the subqueries altogether, for example pre-computing as a [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), or a [materialized view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-materialized-view-as-select-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest).

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of conditions and joined tables before getting the date filter from table `valyuta_declarations`. Please filter this table before joining the other tables. Try below updated query.

```
select * from
(select t.id,
        t.num,
        t.declaration_Date,
        ct.type,
        g.name,
        g.tnved_code,
        g.g31_amount,
        g.brutto,
        g.netto,
        case
            when t.state = 1 then
                1
            else
                0
            end
env,
        CASE
            WHEN ct.type = 1 THEN
                t.g2_code2
            ELSE
                '200794867'
            END as seller_tin,
        CASE
            WHEN ct.type = 1 THEN
                '200794867'
            ELSE
                t.g8_code2
            END as buyer_tin,
        CASE
            WHEN ct.type = 1 THEN
                t.g2_name
            ELSE
                t.g8_name
            END as seller_name,
        CASE
            WHEN ct.type = 2 THEN
                t.g8_name
            ELSE
                t.g2_name
            END                                       as buyer_name,
        sum(g.cost_facture * t.curr_Course)           as cost_Facture,
        SUM(g1.good_payment_27 + g2.good_pay_late_27) as good_payment_27,
        SUM(g1.good_payment_29 + g2.good_pay_late_29) as good_payment_29
    from 
        (select id, num, declaration_Date, type, g1_b
            from valyuta_declarations
            where declaration_date between to_date('01-01-2022','dd-mm-yyyy') and to_date('31-03-2022','dd-mm-yyyy')) t,
    inner join valyuta_CONTRACT_SUB_TYPES ct on t.type = ct.short_name
    inner join valyuta_GOODS g on t.id = g.DECLARATION_ID
    inner join (select g.id,
              g.declaration_id,
              g.cost_facture,
              SUM(CASE
                      WHEN gp.payment_code = 27 THEN
                          gp.payment_amount
                      ELSE
                          0
                  END) as good_payment_27,
              SUM(CASE
                      WHEN gp.payment_code = 29 THEN
                          gp.payment_amount
                      ELSE
                          0
                  END) as good_payment_29
           from valyuta_goods g, 
                valyuta_good_payments gp
           where g.id = gp.good_id(+)
           group by g.id, g.declaration_id, g.cost_facture) g1 on g.id = g1.id
    inner join(select g.id,
              g.declaration_id,
              g.cost_facture,
              SUM(CASE
                      WHEN gpl.L_G47_TYPE = 27 THEN
                          gpl.L_G47_SUM
                      ELSE
                          0
                  END) as good_pay_late_27,
              SUM(CASE
                      WHEN gpl.L_G47_TYPE = 29 THEN
                          gpl.L_G47_SUM
                      ELSE
                          0
                  END) as good_pay_late_29
       from valyuta_goods g,
            valyuta_GOOD_PAY_LATE gpl
       where g.id = gpl.good_id(+)
       group by g.id, g.declaration_id, g.cost_facture) g2 on g.id = g2.id
 where 
  
    ((ct.type = 1 and t.g1_b in (10, 11)) or (ct.type = 2 and t.g1_b = 40))
 GROUP BY t.id,
          t.num,
          t.declaration_Date,
          t.state,
          ct.type,
          g.name,
          g.tnved_code,
          g.g31_amount,
          g.brutto,
          g.netto,
          t.G2_CODE2,
          t.G2_NAME,
          t.g8_code2,
          t.g8_name) a
where a.type = 1 and a.env = 1  
and seller_tin in ('302857893')
```